# Google places api is giving me error Daily Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

After a lot of hassle I have managed to setup places API on my site.
But just after one search its says **You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an [active billing account](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account)**

Everyone is saying there is 1000 search I get free/day. After setup of Billing Account I will get more. So I want to clarify this because I just got 1 search.

Comment: You must enable billing with a credit card.

Comment: i have added debit card, not credit card. is it the problem ?

Comment: ideally it should be credit card. make sure that the card information is verified by google. Also check your quota limit in your dev console. By default it is 2400 req/day

Comment: how to increase limit? currently it is 2400 request/day